# MySQL - IF Query with STR_TO_DATE

Tags: mysql, if-statement

Greetings Stackian Overflowers,

I'm trying to overwrite data in an existing column and do a STR_TO_DATE in the case it is already set.

Here's the code :

```
SELECT IF(columnA = '../../..' , '0000/00/00' , STR_TO_DATE(columnA, '%m/%d/%Y) 
FROM tablename
WHERE extract_date = '2018-12-31';
```

In all reality, I must use this logic to make an update on the table. I tried this :

```
UPDATE tablename
IF columnA = '../../..' THEN
SET columnA = '0000-00-00' ELSE
SET columnA = STR_TO_DATE(columnA,'%m/%d/%Y);
```

Could use any help on the matter.

Comment: What does `columnA` contain? Can you attach example of data?

Comment: Dates. Which are input as a String due to complications with the source file. Sadly, can't change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's `REGEXP` operator comes in handy here:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET date_col = CASE WHEN columnA REGEXP '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}'
                    THEN STR_TO_DATE(columnA, '%m/%d/%Y)
                    ELSE NULL END;
```

It doesn't make sense to update `columnA` from a string to a date, because the types don't match.  A better strategy is to create a new column to store the date.  Also, I recommend using `NULL`, not `0000-00-00`, to represent a date string that could not be parsed.

Note that the regex I used is not foolproof and does not completely validate your date strings.  But it should at least weed out string data which is really off.

Comment: Problem is I can't add a column or I would. All data is submitted as Strings due to a third party factor which I have no control over.. I could get along with the Null option.  
This pretty much converts the string to a date if it fits the reg, else it just nulls it, correct?

Comment: You _can't_ put a bona fide date value into a text column.  Databases don't work that way (except for SQLIte, but let's not go there right now).

Comment: What if I want to just change the format. The initial format is m/d/y and I want it to be yyyy/mm/dd. Can't I just do that without worries?

I did try with the select and it seemed to work, but it might not for the Update, is my understanding fair?

Comment: Dates don't really have an internal format that you control in this way.  You absolutely should be using a date column, and if you want to render those dates in a certain format, then use `DATE_FORMAT`.

Comment: Much obliged. Thank you very much.